# Comparing dates using logical operator

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have this excel sheet which I will be used to send notification

[image]

The first 3 columns contain date of expiry and next 3 column notify 1 , notify 2, notify 3 contain a date which is 30 days prior to the expiry date.

I need to compare the dates in notify 1 , notify 2 and notify 3 and if the date in any of the column is equal to current date then the status column must be TRUE else FALSE

I tried this formula but I get a error invalid formula

```
=IF(OR(datevalue(Now()) =J2),(datevalue(Now()) =k2), (datevalue(Now()) =L2), (datevalue(Now()) =M2), (datevalue(Now()) =N2), (datevalue(Now()) =O2), (datevalue(Now()) =P2), "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your parenthesis groupings are wrong. You need to form it so that the list for the `OR` is within one parenthesis pair; `OR(a=b,c=d,e=f)`.
2. Instead of using `DATEVALUE(NOW())`, you can use `TODAY()`.